# Preg Match Issues in validation email id

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Why code below returns emails ID as false or invalid?

```
<?php
    $okay = preg_match(
        '/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/', 
        "caree.india.support@gmail.com"
    );
    echo $okay;
?>
```

Comment: Do what Tom wrote. Don't reinvent what's already there and is working. But just for the sake of answering why your regex failed: You didn't allow dots `\.`.

Comment: @MyBrainHurts bracket expressions don't need escaping dots: `/^[A-z0-9_\-.]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/` (notice the added dot at the end of the first bracket)

Comment: @AlexBay Your absolutely right - guess I wanted to make sure it doesn't get confused with the wild card. Should have wrote it your way!

Comment: 2 to 4 character for TLD is very poor, see: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: MyBrainHurts , I am NOT inventing , I copied the code and tried and when it didn't work , i asked here.  I am a very very very new bie ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is a function from PHP itself to validate emails, I suggest using that instead of a regex.

```
<?php
    $email_a = 'caree.india.support@gmail.com';
    $email_b = 'Random words';

    if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "This ($email_a) email address is considered valid.";
    }
    if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "This ($email_b) email address is considered valid.";
    }
?>
```

More on this can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php